# How to read the value of a row field whose name is in another field

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a variable A with the name of a column from table TABLE, and I have a row B from TABLE how can I do something like
value := B.A in plpgsql in Postgresql

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` to parameterize any identifiers. And pass the row value as data with the `USING` clause Like:

```
EXEXUTE format('SELECT $1.%I ', A)
USING B
INTO  value_variable; -- with matching data type!
```

Related:

- [EXECUTE...INTO...USING statement in PL/pgSQL can't execute into a record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547666/execute-into-using-statement-in-pl-pgsql-cant-execute-into-a-record/17665049#17665049)