# PLPGSQL Dynamic Query - ERROR:PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block lin

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-queries

I have been trying to run the following [query](https://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql06.html#:%7E:text=VACUUM%0A%0Atestdb%3D%23-,SELECT%20count(*)%20as%20%22number%20of%20pages%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pg_size_pretty(cast(avg(avail)%20as%20bigint))%20as%20%22Av.%20freespace%20size%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20round(100%20*%20avg(avail)/8192%20%2C2)%20as%20%22Av.%20freespace%20ratio%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FROM%20pg_freespace(%27accounts%27)%3B,-number%20of%20pages) for multiple tables:

```
SELECT count(*) as "number of pages",
       pg_size_pretty(cast(avg(avail) as bigint)) as "Av. freespace size",
       round(100 * avg(avail)/8192 ,2) as "Av. freespace ratio"
       FROM pg_freespace('accounts');
```

What I have managed to write so far is:

```
do
$body$
declare
temprow record;
l_nop decimal;
l_pct decimal;
l_ratio decimal;
l_context text;
l_context_detail text;
tablex text;
begin
FOR temprow IN
    select table_schema, table_name, pg_relation_size('"'||table_schema||'"."'||table_name||'"')/1024/1024 as size_mb from information_schema.tables
    where table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog') order by size_mb desc limit 100
    LOOP
begin
    raise notice 'for table %.% ', temprow.table_schema, temprow.table_name;
    execute E'SELECT count(*), pg_size_pretty(cast(avg(avail) as bigint)), round(100 * avg(avail)/8192 ,2)  FROM pg_freespace(\'$1.$2\')'  using temprow.table_schema, temprow.table_name into l_nop, l_pct, l_ratio;
EXCEPTION
WHEN others THEN GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS
    l_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'ERROR:%', l_context;
end;
    END LOOP;
end;
$body$;
```

Yet, I get

```
NOTICE:  check1
NOTICE:  for table public.pg_hist_stat_statements_history
NOTICE:  ERROR:PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 18 at EXECUTE
```

I have tried different dynamic commands practices like format, but did not help. Also, tried to implement what I found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547666/execute-into-using-statement-in-pl-pgsql-cant-execute-into-a-record) to get this point. What am I missing? Also, is it possible to write this PLPGSQL block as an SQL? My first thought was using the `lateral` join but pg_freespace pipelined function, so it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "*but pg_freespace pipelined function*", `LATERAL` should work?

Comment: Bergi, sorry I missed this comment. With the pipelined functions I meant [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/pipelined-table-functions). TL;DR: `passing data back to the calling query before the function is completed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use dynamic SQL here. [`pg_freespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgfreespacemap.html) takes a table OID as its argument, which you can directly get from the first query. I'd use [`pg_catalog.pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) though not `information_schema.tables`:

```
SELECT
  relnamespace::regnamespace AS table_schema,
  relname AS table_name,
  pg_relation_size(oid)/1024/1024 as size_mb,
  space.*
FROM pg_class,
LATERAL (
  SELECT
    count(*),
    pg_size_pretty(cast(avg(avail) as bigint)),
    round(100 * avg(avail)/8192 ,2)
  FROM pg_freespace(oid)
) AS space
WHERE relkind = 'r'
  AND relnamespace NOT IN ('information_schema'::regnamespace, 'pg_catalog'::regnamespace)
ORDER BY size_mb DESC
LIMIT 100
```

or more traditional with a `GROUP BY` instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT
  relnamespace::regnamespace AS table_schema,
  relname AS table_name,
  pg_relation_size(oid)/1024/1024 as size_mb,
  count(*),
  pg_size_pretty(cast(avg(avail) as bigint)),
  round(100 * avg(avail)/8192 ,2)
FROM pg_class, LATERAL pg_freespace(oid)
WHERE relkind = 'r'
  AND relnamespace NOT IN ('information_schema'::regnamespace, 'pg_catalog'::regnamespace)
GROUP BY relnamespace, relname, oid
ORDER BY size_mb DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I have read the pg_freespace uses oid, but I just wanted to use hard way to be honest to learn more :). By the way, what is my mistake in the PLPGSQL, do you have any idea?

Comment: Doing it the "hard way" from `information_schema` would probably be `pg_freespace((quote_ident(table_schema)||'.'||quote_ident(table_name))::regclass::oid)` or `pg_freespace((format('%I.%i', table_schema, table_name))::regclass::oid)`

Comment: No idea what the PLPGSQL problem is, sorry